# Visual Studio 2010 Plugin - How to add error in Error List Window

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I have created one plugin in Visual Studio 2010. This plugin access all the .cs files and validate the code.

Now my requirement is to show the error/warnings. And i want to show that in visual studio error list window.

I googled for one day but no success. So can anyone give me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need: [Writing to the VS ErrorList](http://vsxexperience.net/2010/03/23/writing-to-the-vs-errorlist/)